# linq to sql: 2 counts as result

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to do the following in LINQ to SQL:

```
    Select count(*) as count_1,
   (select count(*) from tableName2) as count_2 FROM tableName
    Where x = y
```

The result should be

```
Column 1 | column 2
--------------------
    50        34
```

Comment: What is that condition `Where x = y`, are x and y columns from each table?

Comment: X = Y is just a where condition on TableName

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a reproducible piece of code...

Comment: I'm only asking for syntax here. The code I posted should be enough for that. I don't have reproducible code yet. It's a problem I will face in the future.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to inform you, especially when you've been registered here for more than 2 years now, that this is not a site for questions like "this is what I want, do it for me". First you need to show your own effort and ask a specific question about what did you try and what didn't work as expected etc... Please take your time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Don't you think I've thought about this and Googled a lot before I posted it? I simply can't find / see how to do it. Here's me admitting my mistake and asking someone to help me on the right track. I'm not asking for a solution. A good read that leads me to my solution would also be nice

Comment: @PoeHaH, I am not sure about the condition part, but may be you are looking some thing as simple as: `var countFromTable = new  {  Count1 = db.tableName.Count(),  Count2 =db.tableName2.Count(),};`

Comment: First place you should take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx and https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is something like this:

```
select 
  (select count(*) 
   from tableName
   where x = y) as count_1, 
  (select count(*) 
   from tableName2) as count_2
```